# REST Assured don't log response body

Tags: java, response, rest-assured

I have method:

```
<https://uri:8080/getVer>
```

This method returns info about version of app. Like that:

```
1.39.1
```

It is text- not xml, not json, not html.

When I try to use this method in REST Assured:

```
        RestAssured.given()
            .log().uri()
            .baseUri("https://uri:8080/")
            .relaxedHTTPSValidation()
            .get("getVer")
            .then()
            .log().all();
```

I do not recived a response body:

**Logs from process:**

> ```
> Request URI:  https://uri:8080/getVer
>
> HTTP/1.1 200 
> Content-Length: 6
> X-Flow-Trace-Id: someTraceId
> Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
> Date: Thu, 30 Dec 2021 19:27:03 GMT
> Set-Cookie: some_cookie; path=/; Httponly; Secure
> Server: some app server
>
> Process finished with exit code 0
> ```

Why i am not received response body? When I try to go to this link on my browser, I recieved a value.

[It is an example from Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GXwi.png)

Comment: It's much better. Now I can store value of body to variable but I don't have response body in my console logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
RestAssured.given()
            .log().uri()
            .baseUri("https://uri:8080/")
            .relaxedHTTPSValidation()
            .get("getVer")
            .then()
            .log().all()
            .extract()
            .response();
```